# How and why parent variable targeting the last node? Has there any reference changed?

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, object-reference

I do understand what happens there. But I want to visualize the whole steps.

Let me clarify:

`list` and `head` are stored across the stack with reference and pointed to the same object. okay.

when it performs `list.next = { val: c, next: null}`, it updates the head like `{ val: 0, next: { val: 1, next: null }}`.

Then `list = list.next` happens means now the list will be `{ val: 1, next: null }`.

Consecutively next, the head is updated to `{ val: 0, next: { val: 1, next: {val: 2, next: null}}}`.

At this point,

1. how the things happen?
2. is there any reference change?
3. Why head variable is indicating the last node?

```js
let head = { val: 0, next: null };

let list = head;

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let c of arr) {
  list.next = { val: c, next: null };
  list = list.next;
}

console.log(head);
```

1. how the things happen?
2. is there any reference change?
3. Why head variable is indicating the last node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The head is not getting updated to `{ val: 0, next: { val: 1, next: null }}`. The head reference never changes, and keeps referencing the same node. To make `head` point to a *different* node, you'd have to make an assignment to `head`, but that never happens after the first and only assignment to it.

On the other hand, `list` *does* get assigned new references, which is to the last node that was created.

> I want to visualize the whole steps.

OK. After the first two statements, where `head` and `list` are assigned, we have the following state:

```
 head  list
  ↓     ↓
┌────────────┐
│ value:   0 │
│ next: null │
└────────────┘
```

The two variables `head` and `list` reference the same node.

In the first iteration of the loop, `c` is 1, and the following *property* assignment is executed -- this is a *mutation* of the node that was created above:

```
list.next = { val: c, next: null };
```

The effect is as follows:

```
 head  list
  ↓     ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value:   0 │   │ value:   1 │
│ next: ────────►│ next: null │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

The next statement is crucial: the *variable* `list` gets a new reference. This is not a mutation, but a variable assignment:

```
list = list.next;
```

And so we get this:

```
 head              list
  ↓                 ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value:   0 │   │ value:   1 │
│ next: ────────►│ next: null │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

Notice how `head` and `list` no longer reference the same node!

Let's do one more iteration of the loop, with `c` equal to 2. First:

```
list.next = { val: c, next: null };
```

...leads to:

```
 head              list
  ↓                 ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value:   0 │   │ value:   1 │   │ value:   2 │
│ next: ────────►│ next: ────────►│ next: null │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

And again `list = list.next;` will assign only to the `list` variable, so we get:

```
 head                              list
  ↓                                 ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value:   0 │   │ value:   1 │   │ value:   2 │
│ next: ────────►│ next: ────────►│ next: null │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

The invariant here is that `head` always references the *first* node of the list, and at the start (and end) of a loop's iteration, `list` references the *last* node in the list.

I hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your question is but let me give an explanation of whats happening:
In js all objects are passed by reference similar to python(guessing by the loop you seem to come from python). Which means the first line creates an object in memory and assigns its address(reference) to 'head'.
Now when you do list = head, both list and head point to the same object. When you do list.next=something, it assigns a new value to the next property of the same object. But both list and head still point to the same parent base object. Only now it has more children.
Next you do list=list.next, at this point the list variable starts pointing to the object held in the next property. Please note that now head and list are pointing to different things. Head still points to the very first parent object. While list keeps pointing to the embeded child object(linkedlist in js is just nested objects). In js 'objects' are just plain dicts in python but have a much wider usage.
Finally when the loop ends the list will be pointing to the last child while head keeps pointing to the base parent object. You can confirm this by just pasting the code in the console of the browser

[image]